# How can I tell Netbeans I'm cross-compiling?

Tags: c, linux, windows, netbeans, cross-compiling

*Please don't answer this as a "How do I cross-compile on Linux for Windows" question, I solved that part. I need some specific instruction on configuring Netbeans. Thank you.*

I'm developing a set of C functions that I want to distribute as a .dll on Windows, and a .so on Linux. (This is going to be used from java as a JNI library, but that's irrelevant to the question).

Development environment is Netbeans 8.2.

I have gcc and mingw installed, and compiling my source code for both targets works.

However, I want to create NetBeans configurations "Linux-Release" and "Windows-Release", with Linux-Release using gcc to create the .so file, and Windows-Release using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc. So I created a Mingw tools collection that refers to the mingw versions of the C compiler:

[image]

In my project properties, I created a Windows_Debug configuration, and told it to use the Mingw tool collection:

[image]

I can use this configuration to get a working Dll. However, the output file will be put into the dist/Windows_Debug/Mingw-**Linux** directory (not dist/Windows_Debug/Mingw-**Windows** as I'd like), and it's put there with a **.so** extension, not **.dll**. I can load this file on Windows when I rename it to .dll, but this will horribly confuse anyone I want to collaborate with.

Naively messing with the CND_DLIB_EXT macro in the generated Makefiles doesn't help at all, they just get overwritten.

I guess I have to either tell Netbeans that the Mingw Tool Collection compiles to Windows, or that the Windows_* configurations compile to Windows, so Netbeans sets the correct values for CND_* and the default output Macro

`${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/libSMAQSJni.${CND_DLIB_EXT}`

in the linker part of Project Properties works again. (Of course, as a workaround, I could just remove the variables from the macro, and replace them with appropriate constants, but I want to do this "right". I haven't found a way to tell Netbeans "this compiles to Windows" anywhere though, neither in the GUI nor in any of the config files. So, how do I do this?